# Upload files on Aws s3 bucket(Private Bucket) from Yii Application and provide file access to users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an application in Yii2. I want to provide the functionality to the admin user to upload files from the admin panel and those files will upload on s3 bucket. My bucket is a private bucket not public. Admin users can upload those images and video files into the bucket, end-user is able to get those files from the android application. I am not able to upload files into a bucket. I got error like 
**S3::putObject(): [InvalidRequest] The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.**

my code is as below

```
public static function uploadToS3($fileTempName, $newfilename, $metaHeaders = array(), $contentType = null) {
    // create AWS object for file upload
    $s3 = new S3(Helpers::yiiparam('s3_access_key'), Helpers::yiiparam('s3_secret_access_key'));
    // connect AWS bucket
    if($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, Helpers::yiiparam('s3_bucket_name') , $newfilename, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)){
        $msg = "S3 Upload Successful."; 
        $s3file='http://'.Helpers::yiiparam('s3_bucket_name').'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$newfilename;
        echo "<img src='$s3file'/>";
        echo 'S3 File URL:'.$s3file;
    }else{
        echo 'msg='.$msg = "S3 Upload Fail.";
        exit;
    }
    exit;            
}
```

s3 class php file code

```
public static function putObjectFile($file, $bucket, $uri, $acl = self::ACL_PRIVATE, $metaHeaders = array(), $contentType = null) {
    return self::putObject(S3::inputFile($file), $bucket, $uri, $acl, $metaHeaders, $contentType);      
}
```

Can you please provide a solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: Need more info. What is the bucket policy? Please also share the code where you attempt upload files. You can mask the access key and secret.

Comment: @Nikhil I have uploaded my code please check